# Why is my CSS animation on the image not working?

Tags: html, css, animation

This is the CSS code I'm using:

```
img {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: movingImage infinite linear 2s infinite;
    animation: movingImage infinite linear 2s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes movingImage {
    0%  {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
    25% {left: 200px; top: 0px;}
    50% {left: 200px; top: 200px;}
    75% {left: 0px; top: 200px;}
    100% {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
}
@keyframes movingImage {
    0%  {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
    25% {left: 200px; top: 0px;}
    50% {left: 200px; top: 200px;}
    75% {left: 0px; top: 200px;}
    100% {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
}
```

And the HTML that I have:

```
<img src="image.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Image">
```

Comment: Try changing the animation rule to `movingImage 2s infinite linear;`

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Do you mind explaining what was changed, there, I know it has something to do with all the different values  it can take but I don't get the ordering that I have to use them in.

Comment: Check the order and number of parameters at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct **[`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)** full syntax is:

> @keyframes name | duration | timing-function | delay | 
>      iteration-count | direction | fill-mode | play-state

In your example:

```
animation: movingImage infinite linear 2s infinite;
```

The last `infinite` is not a valid value anymore, as you already declared it earlier.

**The correct full syntax is:**

```
animation: movingImage 2s linear 0s infinite normal none running;
```

Or the shorten version:

```
animation: movingImage 2s linear infinite;
```

[**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5omkn50y/)

```css
img {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: movingImage 2s linear infinite;
    animation: movingImage 2s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes movingImage {
    0%  {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
    25% {left: 200px; top: 0px;}
    50% {left: 200px; top: 200px;}
    75% {left: 0px; top: 200px;}
    100% {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
}
@keyframes movingImage {
    0%  {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
    25% {left: 200px; top: 0px;}
    50% {left: 200px; top: 200px;}
    75% {left: 0px; top: 200px;}
    100% {left: 0px; top: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<img src="image.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Image">
```